# How to extract innerHTML from tag using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the innerHTML from a tag using the following code:

```
theurl = "http://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=Darshan"
thepage = urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
rank = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"tierRank"})
```

However I am getting `[< span class="tierRank" > Master < /span >]` instead.
What I want to show is the value "Master" only.

Using `soup.get_text` instead of `soup.findall` doesn't work.

I tried adding `.text` and `.string` to the end of last line but that did not work either.

Comment: *adding `.text` and `.string` to the end of last line* didn't work because you're trying to use that on a list. You'll simply have to access the first element using `[0]` and get the text using `soup.findAll('span',{"class":"tierRank"})[0].text`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`soup.findAll('span',{"class":"tierRank"})` returns a *list* of elements that match `<span class="tierRank">`.

1. You want the first element from that list.
2. You want the `innerHtml` from that element, which can be accessed by the `decode_contents()` method.

All together:

```
rank = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"tierRank"})[0].decode_contents()
```

This will store "Master" in `rank`.

Comment: Why use `decode_contents()` when you can use `.text` or `.get_text()`? I think this suggestion misguided the OP and he asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934878/how-to-extract-the-link-of-the-first-gallery-on-imgur-using-bs4-and-urllib) where he tried to use this for getting something different.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar is correct that `Tag#text` would work in this specific case.  `Tag#decode_contents` will return the innerHTML with any included HTML tags intact, and also works for plain strings.

Comment: .text will get only text part. Not the html.

Answer (score 2):

if you want as a bulk
you can use the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:\\test.html"), "html.parser")

for data1 in soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'YourClass'}):
    print(data1.decode_contents(), sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .decode_contents() if you want innerHTML (with html tags)
use .text if you want innerText (no html tags)