# How to extract the link of the first gallery on imgur using BS4 and urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the gallery link of the first result on an imgur search.

```
theurl = "https://imgur.com/search?q=" +text
thepage = urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
link = soup.findAll('a',{"class":"image-list-link"})[0].decode_contents()
```

Here is what is being displayed for link:
[image: Here is what is being displayed for link]

I am mainly trying to get the href value from only this section (the first result for the search)

Here is what the inspect element looks like:
[image: Here is what the inspect element looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's pretty easy to accomplish what you're trying to do. As shown in the image, the `href` of first image (or any image for that matter) is located inside the `<a>` tag with the attribute `class="image-list-link"`. So, you can use the `find()` function, which returns the first match found. And then, use `['href']` to get the link.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://imgur.com/search?q=python')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

first_image_link = soup.find('a', class_='image-list-link')['href']
print(first_image_link)
# /gallery/AxKwQ2c
```

---

If you want to get the links for all the images, you can use a list comprehension.

```
all_image_links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='image-list-link')]
```