# Getting the text of an HTML <a> tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script using BeautifulSoup to findAll the information of a certain class, I would like to get out the text of an a tag.

What I mean is like:

```
<a href="/weather">Weather</a>
```

Getting the text after the href that says Weather.

Each of those a tags are in a div which I am fetching using

```
blank = soup.findAll(attrs={"blank"})
```

And I'm getting returned the whole class.

I have tried using .decode_contents() but:

I want the action to be performed on every element, and with .decode_contents from what I can see you need to specify which element in the list you want it to be performed on.

It still returns the whole class and `<a>` element and not just the "Weather" I wanted it to.

How would I find just the text in the `<a>` tag and return it to console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract innerHTML from tag using BeautifulSoup in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911406/how-to-extract-innerhtml-from-tag-using-beautifulsoup-in-python)

Comment: use `.text` or `.get_text()` - ie. `blank.find('a').text` , `blank.find('a').get_text()`

Comment: `for item in blank.find_all('a'): print(item.text)`

Comment: @furas thank you so much! how would you find all the ('a') in a certain class?

Comment: `.find_all('a')` - ie. `find(class_="name").find_all('a')`. Or using CSS selector `.select(".class_name a")`

Comment: @furas you can only do that with one class, how could you do it with every one of the classes?

I've tried doing 
    ```for item in soup.find_all(attrs={"blank"}).find_all('a'):```
but that doesnt work, you can only do:
    ```for item in soup.find(attrs={"star-container"}).find_all('a'):```
showing one of them.

Comment: you can use two `for`-loops like `for item in soup.find_all(attrs={"blank"}): for item2 in item.find_all('a'): item2.text`

Answer (score 0):

```
blank = soup.find_all('a')
blank.attrs['href']
```

This will return a list (blank) of all the inner text present in all the `<a>` tags present in the html data that is parsed.

For printing the data :

```
for blank in soup.find_all("a"):
    print("Inner Text: {}".format(blank.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector for specific element.

```
for item in soup.select('a[href*="weather"]'):
  print(item.text)
```